# Подсчитать максимальное количество отрицательных элементов идущих подряд

Tags: c++, массивы

Нужно подсчитать максимальное количество отрицательных элементов идущих подряд. Что-то не могу понять как сделать правильно. На данный момент считает просто все отрицательные элементы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int n = 15;
    bool change = true;
    int arr[n], m = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10 - 5;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    int maxcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (arr[i] < 0) {
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j] < 0) {
                    count++;
                    if (count > maxcount) { maxcount = count; }
                    cout << count << " ";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl << maxcount << endl;
}
```

Comment: 1) это не c++ а с, второе, отформатируйте ваш вопрос

Comment: @strangeqargo это с++

Comment: это `c++` только потому, что с является его подмножеством, фактически, вы не используете никаких средств с++, только средства доступные `c`, исключая cout, конечно

Comment: массив вы не сортировали, следовательно, идущих подряд элементов вы и получить не можете (тут от вашей задачи зависит, может вам и не сортированные нужны, а рэндомные). если бы это был c++, вы бы сделали vector.sort()

Comment: @strangeqargo но все же с++. лутше помогите чем этот спор ни о чем

Comment: @strangeqargo вот мне как раз и без сортировки нужно

Comment: @strangeqargo и без библиотек

Comment: значит вам нужен как минимум еще одна переменная, в которой вы будете хранить максимальное количество совпадений, а не просто переменная count. И не забудьте сообщить преподавателю вашего ВУЗа, если вы не сами учите, что он дебил.

Comment: @strangeqargo судя с ваших слов и выше описанного - это только ваше предположение. а мне нужен конкретный ответ

Comment: @strangeqargo почему же он дебил?

Comment: вы увеличиваете count++, значит все что вы получаете, количество всех отрицательных чисел. вам нужно укладывать в какую-то переменную 1) количество совпадений, 2) сбрасывать каунт 2) если следующий каунт > чем в переменной, заменяете значение, в итоге вы получите максимальное значение в конце цикла.... а, я вижу, maxcount у вас есть уже. гы. значит ошибка где-то.

Comment: потому, что языку с++ не учат на примерах из языка с.

Comment: @strangeqargo и что в этом плохого? это отличные задания. всего от начала учебы - 1.5 мес. и я там сбрасывал, и заменял, не то чтото делаю

Comment: @strangeqargo `vector.sort()` - только вот нет такого в c++ :) если мы о `std::vector` говорим.

Comment: `std::sort`, конечно же.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] < 0) {
                count++;
                if (count > maxcount) { maxcount = count; }

            }else{
                count = 0; //cбрасывать значение count кто будет?
            }
        }
```

пробный запуск:

```
-3 -5 -4 3 4 -5 1 0 -3 -1 -1 -2 -5 -5 0 

6
```

Comment: Одновременно)))

Comment: дааа, все работает) теперь огромное спасибо=)

Answer (score 6):

Чуточку [функциональщины](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) на любителя:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main()
{
    int v[] { -2, 0, 2, -1, -2, -11, -2, 3, 5, 1, -1, -1, 1, -2, -1, 2 };

    int m = ranges::max(v 
        | ranges::view::group_by([](int a, int b){return (a < 0) && (b < 0);})
        | ranges::view::transform(ranges::distance)
    );

    assert(m == 4);
}
```

Вот если бы [еще](https://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4128.html) диапазоны в стандартную библиотеку заапрувили.. Да ещё и с [параллельными](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P0024R2.html) алгоритмами.. Ммм...

Comment: на Питоне: [`max(sum(1 for _ in same_sign) for isnegative, same_sign in groupby(v, key=lambda x: x < 0) if isnegative)`](http://ideone.com/9eblFI)

Comment: @jfs крутяк, не понял только почему `key` явно указан для `groupby`

Comment: по умолчанию `key=lambda  x: x`, поэтому `groupby()` сгруппирует только  *идущие подряд одинаковые* элементы, например, если элементы в `v` отсортированы, то уникальные элементы можно получить: `uniq = map(itemgetter(0), groupby(v))`. В примере `key=lambda x: x < 0` ведёт к группировке элементов с одинаковым знаком. `same_sign` это группа подряд идущих элементов с одинаковым знаком, `isnegative` это знак (отрицательный ли).

Comment: @jfs не, не, я не прально выразился, имел ввиду вот этот кусок: `key=`, второй аргумент позиционный же. В том смысле, что так тоже должно работать по идее: `groupby(ints, lambda x: x < 0)`

Comment: Почему именованный параметр использован, вместо позиционного? -- Привычка. Если первый аргумент более сложен, то `key=` помогает визуально. Именованные параметры в целом легче (я не всегда порядок аргументов помню -- например, без документации не смогу сказать, принимает ли `itertools.groupby()` ещё какие параметры и какой у них порядок).

Comment: @jfs Просто иногда вижу такое, и нет мыслей почему именно так. И ещё вопрос, как к с специалисту, стоит ли использовать встроенную функцию `math.copysign` вместо лямбды: https://repl.it/ChWL/5  какие могут быть подводные камни.

Comment: я использовал `lambda x: x < 0` для читаемости. В противном случае, можно `partial(operator.gt, 0)` использовать, что менее читаемо (равнозначен: `lambda x: 0 > x`).

Comment: @jfs точно, есть же operator-ы, все понял, спасибо.

Comment: @jfs ещё момент такой - если отрицательных чисел нет, то `max` упадет с `ValueError`.

Comment: Если хочется учесть этот случай, то можно `default=0` параметр в `max()` передать или использовать `max(itertools.chain(sizes, [0]))`.

Answer (score 5):

```
int main()
{
    int a[12] {-1, -2, -11, -2, 3, 5, 1, -1, -1, 1, -2, -1};

    unsigned current = 0, maxnegative = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        if (a[i] < 0) {
            ++current;
            if (current > maxnegative) maxnegative = current;
        } else {
            current = 0;
        }
    }

    cout << maxnegative << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: проклятье! пусть победит удачливый! плюсую

Answer (score 3):

Может кому то [реактивный](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxCpp) вариант понадобится:

```
#include <vector>
#include <rxcpp/rx.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ -1, -2, -11, -2, 3, 5, 1, -1, -1, 1, -2, -1, 1, 2, 1, 0 };

    auto m = rxcpp::observable<>::iterate(v)
        .scan(0, [](int a, int i) { return (i < 0) ? a + 1 : 0; })
        .scan(0, [](int a, int i) { return std::max<int>(a, i); })
        .distinct_until_changed();

    m | rxcpp::operators::subscribe<int>(rxcpp::util::println(std::cout));
}
```

Фишка в возможности использования входных данных, растянутых по времени. При каждом появлении во входном потоке нового значения, если результат меняется, наблюдатель получит событие. То, что это ультросовременно и риактивно, наверное и так понятно )

[image: Everything is a stream]